# How to put boolean value on CloudWatchEvent pattern in SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam

I'm using SAM and my lambda is triggered by CloudWatchEvents. I'm trying to match events that have "campaign" in their details as in [this example of the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-exists-matching). This is the code of the lambda Events property in my sam template:

```
            feedPost:
                Type: CloudWatchEvent
                Properties:
                    EventBusName: my_bus
                    Pattern:
                        source:
                            - mySource
                        detail:
                            campaign:
                                - exists: true
```

The problem is that when on deployment, the following error arises:

> Event pattern is not valid. Reason: exists match pattern must be
>   either true or false. at [Source: (String)"{
>   "source":["mySource"],"detail":{"campaign":[{"exists":"true"}]}}";

Apparently it is transforming true into an string. How can I make this work?

Comment: One thing that could be tried is to use json notation: `{"campaign":["exists":true]}` for either `detail` or entire `Pattern`.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know you could put json in a yaml, but after trying that, it was the same

Comment: Can you create the rule manually in CW Events. And then use cli [describe-rule](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/events/describe-rule.html) to view its internal structure, and check how exactly is this event represented?

Comment: I figured a different pattern that fits my needs and created an issue for this on GitHub. Hopefully it will get fixed sometime

Comment: Do you have the link to the issue? And could you share the solution? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this. I opened this issue. https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1596

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Hopefully it will get fixed. Interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Know issue with CloudFormation: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1455

No workarounds available for now.